# How to use multiple route in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Check the RouteConfig.cs file code bellow on mvc5 project. The first `Default` route which is configured for return home page is works fine. But the second one which i made to send traffic to `Product` controller is not working. The way i am trying to hit the controller is- `http://localhost:50070/Product/somepage/good-product`

The error i am getting is:

> The resource cannot be found.

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Product",
                url: "Product/{pagename}/{slug}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", slug = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "Demo.Controllers" }
            );


        }
    }
```

Comment: Make default route mapping after all other mappings

Comment: I suggest using [`Route` attribute](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/). Using multiple `MapRoute` will bloat your code and will make hard to maintain.

Comment: Default route should always be the last one in the Route table as Roman suggested.

Comment: @RomanDoskoch you are badass saved my day bro! Thanks a lot. you can answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is in order of route mappings. Routes are matched in mapping order - in your case `Product/somepage/good-product` matches default route template and it is chosen. But you don't have action `Somepage` on `Product` controller.

Default route mapping should be the last mapping (just change the order):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Product",
    url: "Product/{pagename}/{slug}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", slug = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "Demo.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change second `routes` like that

Use `controller` in order to `pagename`

```
routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Product",
       url: "Product/{controller}/{slug}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", slug = UrlParameter.Optional },
       namespaces: new[] { "Demo.Controllers" }
);
```